# .SaveAs method not working in excel with MSXML2.DOMDocument object

Tags: xml, excel

So I am trying to save my vb script that converts cell values to xml in a specific file path but when I try to use .SaveAs I get an error that the object doesn't support this method. I am using the below code to initialize my script:

```
Set oXMLDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
Set oPI = oXMLDoc.createProcessingInstruction("xml", "version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8"" standalone=""no""")
Set oRoot = oXMLDoc.createNode(1, "VanwykXML", "")
Call oRoot.setAttribute("version", "1.0")
oXMLDoc.appendChild oRoot
oXMLDoc.InsertBefore oPI, oXMLDoc.ChildNodes.Item(0)
```

Then I am using .createNode and .createtextNode to enter my data

Finally I am trying to Save As:

```
oXMLDoc.SaveAs "C:\CamelotFormulaTest.xml"
```

This save method works but I have no control to the path:

```
oXMLDoc.Save "CamelotFormulaTest.xml"
```

Is there someway to get the .SaveAs method to work?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such method `SaveAs`. You should stick with the [`Save`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753769(v=vs.85).aspx) method, and concatenate the desired path in your argument:

```
oXMLDoc.Save "C:\CamelotFormulaTest.xml"
```